# Why won't the text inside <div> change, when it clearly should?

Tags: javascript, html

Why won't the text inside the  tags change, when it clearly should change? Can anyone help?
Here is  my HTML and JS code:

```
function pickStick(); {
    weapon = "Stick";
    weapondamage = 1;
    document.getElementById("weapon").innerHTML = "Weapon: ";

}
```

And...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
<br><br>
<div id="weapon">You see a stick. You can <a href="" onclick="pickStick()">pick it up.</a></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: remove the semicolon in function definition.

Comment: Might not be the problem, but you should change your function definition from `function pickStick(); {` to `function pickStick() {`

Answer (score 3):

You have a semicolon after your function name ( `function pickStick();` ), you need to remove that:

```
function pickStick() {
    weapon = "Stick";
    weapondamage = 1;
    document.getElementById("weapon").innerHTML = "Weapon: ";

}
```

Then you may want to remove the `href` from your `<a>` so it doesn't move to a new page, or replace it with `href="#"`:

```
<a href="#" onclick="pickStick();">pick it up.</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update 2 things

**JS update**

Replace

```
function pickStick(); {
```

with

```
function pickStick() {
```

**Markup update**

Replace

```
<a href="" onclick="pickStick()">
```

with

```
<a href="#" onclick="pickStick()">
```

or

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="pickStick()">
```

For reference - http://plnkr.co/edit/wu1y9OA1Ml1gQPCEQImB?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```js
function pickStick() {
    weapon = "Stick";
    weapondamage = 1;
    document.getElementById("weapon").innerHTML = "Weapon: ";
}
```

```html
<div id="weapon">You see a stick. You can <a href="#" onclick="pickStick()">pick it up.</a>
```

So the problem is probably due to you having a semi-colon in your function definition, or the missing pound sign (`#`) in your anchor.